# 'CONTEXT' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, indexing, transient

No clue why I'm getting this error in my ASP MVC application:

```
'themeContext' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[MICSgroupHospital.Models.Theme(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a sub-query to iterate over the collection. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 16.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException: 'themeContext' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[MICSgroupHospital.Models.Theme(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a sub-query to iterate over the collection. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 16.

Source Error: 


Line 18:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             return View(db.themeContext.ToList());
Line 21:         }
Line 22:
```

My create view is working just fine, and submitting what I enter into it inside the database, so I think my connection string is fine.

Here's my model:

```
    namespace MICSgroupHospital.Models
{
    [Table("THEMES")]
    public class Theme
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Hex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's my context class:

```
namespace MICSgroupHospital.Models
{
    public class ThemeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Theme> themeContext { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the culprit action in my controller (the controller was auto generated, as well as the views):

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.themeContext.ToList());
        }
```

The connection string:

```
<add name="ThemeContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ThemeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated...

*edit*: Still no luck. I've tried recreating the database connection.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do var records = db.themeContext.ToList() and then return View(records)? When you do that and you set a break point on return does it blow up before it hits break?

Comment: @mwwallace8 yes, unfortunately. Oh let me see with break point..

Comment: @mwwallace8 The break appears to be occuring at the "var records" line. An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Inserts work but that doesn't.. Does retrieving a single item work? /details/1?

Comment: @mwwallace8 That's right, just double checked that inserts do work (although the redirect to the index page does not). I tried viewing the details of item 1 and got a similar transient error. Line 32:             Theme theme = db.themeContext.Find(id); is the line giving the problem. Yes there is data inside the table for id 1.

Comment: @mwwallace8 Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be a shot in the dark at this point. It all looks fairly normal to me. I might try changing some of the names...Ex : 'themeContext' to be 'themeDB' and re-do the code-first steps. That way your connection string, context class and context variable aren't so similar. It seems like it could be something weird about the naming? Like I said, shot in the dark.

Comment: @mwwallace8 So I basically just redid my whole themes feature and now it works. I remember I changed the name around a lot for the THEME table and the theme.cs model, so maybe visual studio was holding on to old values and not mapping to the new ones properly.

Comment: Very good! Glad it's fixed.

Comment: @mwwallace8 Me too, but it leaves a bitter taste in my mouth about Visual Studio...I'm still not sure why the error happened, and it's unfortunate the amount of effort I had to go to in order to solve this issue.

Comment: Understandable. In that situation with code-first if you're just starting out a project it's sometimes easiest for me to sort of 'start over' by deleting the configuration.cs and migrations, drop table, etc if things feel unstable or out of sync. Doing all that generally only takes a few minutes and gets it all syncd up.