# In ASP MVC, why do all my views besides create give me this error, regarding Transient.Collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, transient

My create view works fine, but when I try to run every view besides the create, I get the following error

```
'themeContext' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[MICSgroupHospital.Models.Theme(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a sub-query to iterate over the collection. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 16.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException: 'themeContext' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[MICSgroupHospital.Models.Theme(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a sub-query to iterate over the collection. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 16.

Source Error: 


Line 18:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             return View(db.themeContext.ToList());
Line 21:         }
Line 22:
```

Basically, the error happens on any view that requires the use of my context class in the get method of the controller. More details can be found here: ['CONTEXT' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436555/context-is-not-a-member-of-transient-collection?noredirect=1#comment60488241_36436555). I apologize for asking the same question twice. Unfortunately my answer did not get any results, so I took stack overflow's advice and made my question title more descriptive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['CONTEXT' is not a member of 'Transient.collection\[\]'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436555/context-is-not-a-member-of-transient-collection)

Comment: >This is going to be deleted as a duplicate. you know you can edit the title after you have made a post.